# Unable to use webpack alias with Jest testing - Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I've created a new repo that replicates this problem found here: https://github.com/davidRoussov/jest-webpack-alias

It's a React app bootstrapped using create-react-app, but it has been ejected. The error I'm getting when I run `npm run test` is this:

```
FAIL  src\components\Parent.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.

  at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.js:7:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Parent.js:2:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Parent.test.js:2:15)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

The component being tested, Parent.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from '@/components/Child';

class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

The test, Parent.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Parent from './Parent';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
      <Parent/>
  ).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

For the webpack config I've only added:

```
function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}
```

And:

```
alias: {

  // Support React Native Web
  // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
  'react-native': 'react-native-web',
  '@': resolve('src')
},
```

The Jest config:

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules"],
    "modulePaths": ["src"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src",
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
```

Jest does not produce errors if `import Child from '@/components/Child';` is replaced with `import Child from './Child';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it's not too late, you forgot to substitute the captured regex groups in the path , like so:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^@(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
},
```

[Link to the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string)